# confluent format changes when data is transfered from oracle to Hive

Tags: hive, schema, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I encounter a problem when using the confluent, I create a jdbc source with ID as the incremental column, and a HDFS sink to write data to Hive.

After all that, I use Hive to explore the data in Hive, what I can see is that the ID column which was "int" in Oracle is turned into "binary" in Hive, and time column which was "date" in Oracle is turned into "timestamp" in Hive.

Here is the detail from the schema register:

```
{
\"type\": \"record\",
\"name\": \"GAYS_KAKOUXINXI\",
\"fields\": [
    {
        \"name\": \"ID\",
        \"type\": [
            \"null\",
            {
                \"type\": \"bytes\",
                \"connect.version\": 1,
                \"connect.parameters\": {
                    \"scale\": \"0\"
                },
                \"connect.name\": \"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal\"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        \"name\": \"DEP_ACTION_FLAG\",
        \"type\": [
            \"null\",
            \"string\"
        ]
    },
    {
        \"name\": \"SBMC\",
        \"type\": [
            \"null\",
            \"string\"
        ]
    },
    {
        \"name\": \"FXMC\",
        \"type\": [
            \"null\",
            \"string\"
        ]
    },
    {
        \"name\": \"FXLX\",
        \"type\": [
            \"null\",
            \"string\"
        ]
    },
    {
        \"name\": \"DD\",
        \"type\": [
            \"null\",
            \"string\"
        ]
    },
    {
        \"name\": \"KKJD\",
        \"type\": [
            \"null\",
            \"string\"
        ]
    },
    {
        \"name\": \"DEP_ACTION_TIME\",
        \"type\": [
            \"null\",
            {
                \"type\": \"long\",
                \"connect.version\": 1,
                \"connect.name\": \"org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Timestamp\"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        \"name\": \"KKMC\",
        \"type\": [
            \"null\",
            \"string\"
        ]
    },
    {
        \"name\": \"GCSJ\",
        \"type\": [
            \"null\",
            \"string\"
        ]
    },
    {
        \"name\": \"CSYS\",
        \"type\": [
            \"null\",
            \"string\"
        ]
    }
],
\"connect.name\": \"GAYS_KAKOUXINXI\"
}
```

Here is my schema-registry.properties：

```
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:18081
kafkastore.connection.url=localhost:2171
kafkastore.topic=_schemas
debug=false
```

Here is my connect-avro-distributed.properties:

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

group.id=connect-cluster


key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081


internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false


config.storage.topic=connect-configs


offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets


status.storage.topic=connect-statuses

producer.interceptor.classes=io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor
consumer.interceptor.classes=io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor
```

How does this happen? And how can I solve this? Is this the problem of config of schema registry?

Best regards,

Feiran

Comment: The Oracle DATE type contains date **and** time, it cannot be converted to a Hive DATE which contains only the date part. Hence the automatic TIMESTAMP conversion.

Comment: AFAIK there is no INT type in Oracle; INTEGER is just an alias to NUMBER(38) which should be converted to a Hive BIGINT. I have no clue why it's BINARY instead.

Comment: It is not the problem of data types in the hive. As I post above, the data in the schema registry (in another word, the data in the kafka) is already transferred from number to byte[] and date to timestamp.

Comment: So it's a problem of Oracle data type support in AVRO. If you want a quick fix, just convert every Oracle field to Varchar2 *(dates in ISO format, etc)*  and convert back in HiveQL.